# Redirection error after posting a comment on a custom type post

Tags: custom-post-types, redirect

I have created a custom post type called portfolio so the permalink structure for this type of posts is like this: mydomain.com/portfolio/post-name/

My issue is that after posting a comment on one of these posts i am redirected to mydomain.com//post-name#comment-id (notice how the word "portfolio" is missing) which causes a redirection loop error. I dont know whats the reason and i dont understand why is this happening.

I double checked my permlink structure and is set as mydomain.com/sample-post/ (post name) and I havent made any changes to the htaccess or whatsoever so what could be happening?

Please help.

EDIT:

This is my custom post type code

```
function my_post_type_portfolio() {
    register_post_type( 'portfolio',
                array(          
                'label' => __('portfolio'), 
                'singular_label' => __('portfolio', 'theme1418'),
                '_builtin' => false,
                'public' => true, 
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'capability_type' => 'page',
                'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/images/icon_portfolio.png',
                'rewrite' => array(
                    'slug' => 'portfolio',
                    'with_front' => FALSE,
                ),
                'supports' => array(
                        'title',
                        'editor',
                        'thumbnail',
                        'excerpt',
                        'custom-fields',
                        'comments')
                    ) 
                );

        register_taxonomy('portfolio_category', 'portfolio', array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'portfolio', 'singular_name' => 'portfolio', "rewrite" => false, "query_var" => true));
}

add_action('init', 'my_post_type_portfolio');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is very easy. After registering you post type:

```
register_post_type( 'portfolio', $args );

flush_rewrite_rules();
```

flush_rewrite_rules will do it for you!

Comment: I tried but it didnt work. Please check again my question, i just added my code.

Comment: I have tried your code in fresh WordPress installation and everything works fine. So you might have some plugin or theme functions causing this error. Are you using custom theme or any theme shop theme?

Comment: I bought this theme and this code was already included in the theme. I asked for support but the guys are still unable to find out the culprit. By the way, the code i posted has some differences with the actual one. In my code, all my labels and slug are in Japanese which count as special characters. I dont know if that could be related.

Comment: Yes that should be the problem. Why don't you try this code that you posted and you will notice it's working. I guess the issue is special characters.

Comment: Because then all my URLs would break. Also, i have special characters in the post names. This should not be a problem since i have many other wordpress sites with special characters in the URLs and they work fine so i dont know whats the problem with this one.

Comment: You can try using different 'slug' without special chars, for testing only and see if it works. If it does then the problem is chars and if it does not then there is something else.

Comment: I tried once but i get a 404 error.

Comment: Oh yes, you will have to flush rewrite rules and visit permalink settings page once.

Comment: Where in my code should i place the flush rewrite rules?

Comment: Just after register_post_type as I posted. So it should be just above register_taxonomy in your code.

Comment: You are right, that fixed it. However having the slug in other language than japanese is not good for my SEO. I wonder if there is another way.

Comment: Well, it's beyond my expertise. So I will let someone else help you who has more insight on special character or specifically Japanese slug.